# What API does Spotify, YouTube music, Apple Music use to integrate with Google Home?

Tags: google-home

What API do apps like Spotify, YouTube Music and Apple music use to handle user intents such as "Ok Google, Play music" - which trigger the selected music service.

The Conversational Actions API mention ["Media Responses"](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/prompts-media), however this API is being deprecated on June 13, 2023.

What APIs do these app use, and what should we do to implement similar features in the future?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- These applications make use of something called as [Media Actions](https://developers.google.com/actions/media) feeds, which lets you describe your media content to Google. This enables users to discover content on Google Search and the Google Assistant and initiate playback of the content directly on the app or platform.
- Google has been working with a limited number of providers at a time to integrate each provider into the feature. You're welcome to read the documentation until we can open it up to more providers.